# Attempt to disprove logic (does this contradict itself)

Tags: logic

I am a beginner at philosophy, but axioms such as logic always interest me.

Please help me find errors or circular reasoning, etc. in this proof.

[I'm not sure if this proof should be formatted.]

Attempt to prove logic, defined as route to solving problem objectively, is ideal (quickest or surest) method to solve a problem "a".

Cannot use logic in proof: would be circular reasoning.

Thus, must use emotional appeal (opposite of logic).

This emotional appeal is a fallacy, thus, if logic can be proved only by a fallacy, logic IS a fallacy.

Comment: Proof presupposes logic. So the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Gödel would squirm in his tomb

Comment: Presenting emotional appeal **as logic** is a fallacy.  I fully agree that we only accept the terms of logic on the basis of a mental favoritism toward "clarity" that is natural to humans, and that this is an entirely emotional reaction.

Comment: I voted to keep this open, but the question still could be made better. Consider revising adding more context.

Answer (score 2):

The wording of your question is a little loose, but I think there is an important question underneath: how do we justify deductive reasoning?

People often ask about how *inductive* reasoning is justified and it is fairly common to hear people talk about "the problem of induction". Induction is actually easy to justify inductively - we've used inductive reasoning a lot in the past and it usually works out pretty well so we have every reasonable expectation that it will continue to work in the future. Is this argument circular? Yes, but not viciously so. Exactly the same consideration applies to deduction. Any attempt to justify deduction is bound to involve deductive reasoning, so is that circular? Again, yes, but not viciously so.

To some extent it depends what you are trying to achieve when asking for a justification of deduction. If someone is 'logically blind' and just cannot see that something follows from something else, then no amount of argument can persuade them. But if you are asking for an explanation of how a proof system in logic can be shown to deliver proofs that match up with our understanding of the relationship between the truths of sentences, then this can be done. When we study logic we distinguish between syntax and semantics. Syntax is concerned with the rules for forming sentences and for constructing formal proofs of one sentence from others. Semantics is concerned with what sentences mean and how their truth values are related. (I'm hugely oversimplifying here, but I'm guessing from your question that you are looking for a simple explanation suitable for a beginner.) For many common logics, including first order predicate logic, we can prove that if an argument is syntactically valid then it is semantically valid (this is called soundness) and that if an argument is semantically valid then it is syntactically valid (this is called completeness).

The fact that we can prove these things gives us confidence that our reasoning is not viciously circular. When you've learned more and are ready to explore the issue in more depth, there is an interesting paper on the subject by Michael Dummett called The Justification of Deduction (in his collection Truth and Other Enigmas).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I sincerely appreciate it. However, semantics and sematics cannot combine to prove logic is reasonable, can they? Also, how can there be a middle gradient between circular and "too hard"? I Apologize if this is too informal a question.

Comment: I would say that what they prove is that deductive logic preserves truth, i.e. that if you start with true premises you won't be led into false conclusions.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, so is it impossible to prove or disprove logic itself as I am trying to do?

Comment: One cannot 'prove' logic to a logically blind person who simple doesn't accept deductive reasoning. One cannot disprove a logic (unless one can show that it is inconsistent) - the most one could say is that it has no useful application.

Answer (score 2):

To explain Luis's comment, if you took your attempted proof, and tried to express it in a formal grammar, you would actually arrive at the same class of self-referential problems that Godel found must arise due to that self-referentiality.

Russel and Whitehead wrote Principia Mathematica, an attempt to build all of logic and mathematics on a small number of axioms (but not 0 axioms, as you deal with in this case).  They actually got quite far using the same mindset you had -- circular logic is illegal.

Godel later showed that, if you can describe all characteristics of the Whole Numbers using your axiomatic system, and can describe the provability of its own statements (as PM did) it must be inconsistent.

Thus one must accept the value of logic intuitively, based on your belief that the axioms behind the logic are valid.  Or, a more robust approach would be to accept that there may be situations where logic can only serve as a guide, not an oracle of truth.

(A related proof was made by Tarksi, showing that any formal language which can prove all of arithmetic over whole numbers and contains the logical negation operator cannot define its own semantic Truth.  Typically the concept of True and False are assumed by most approaches to logic)

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question as asking whether one can proof the correctness of the logic we use for proving theorems.

Already this formulation of the question shows a certain circularity, because each proof uses logical reasoning.

Theories of logic like other mathematical theories can be axiomatized. One has a certain freedom to choose the axioms. Accordingly there are several axiomatic systems of logic: 2-valued propositional logic with the tertium non datur as axiom, 3-valued logic, many-valued logic, predicate logic, paraconsistent logic which allows contradictory propositions, fuzzy logic ... . The minimal requirement is that the logical theory is free from internal contradictions.

Alike to any other theory one cannot prove that the axioms of a certain logical theory are true. They are supposed as premiss of the whole theory. But one can ask whether a certain logical theory applies successfully in our every-day reasoning or in scientific reasoning. Both the 2-valued propositional logic as well as predicate calculus has shown to be useful and reliable.

Another question deals with the rules of reasoning, i.e. with the syllogisms. A typical syllogism is modus ponens: *If A => B and A, then B.* I have never seen different logical theories employing different syllogisms. But of course, this observation does not prove the correctness of the syllogisms.

Answer (score 1):

Modern logic as we now know it is a *formal axiomatic* system that establishes a relationship between one set of statements known as *premises* and another set of statements known as *conclusions.*  *[Formal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system)* means that it is an artificial, constructed, consistent, rule-governed system, and *[axiomatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom)* means that we accept its basic rules as givens as a prerequisite for using the system.

It is believed that logic is a truth-preserving set of transformations, such that if you are able create a set of premises that accurately and "truthfully" formalize a real-world state of affairs, all valid conclusions reached by logic will preserve the truthfulness of the premises.  However, this cannot be proved from within logic.  In the most common systems of logic, you cannot even frame a statement that speaks about the system of logic, because allowing self-referential statements was found to lead to [paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox#Logical_paradox) fatal to the project of logic.

If you are speaking about a philosophical commitment to the concept that all beliefs must be certified by logic, that commitment itself cannot be certified by logic.  In general form, this is a well-known result often considered to have doomed the philosophy of "[verificationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verificationism)" (a strict form of logical positivism).  The commitment to any given framework of justification cannot be self-justified.